# Script to fetch system information shows too much detail

Tags: powershell

I wrote the following script to get Windows system information like CPU count, CPU model, Memory and Serial no.

```psh
param (
    [string]$a
)

Function proc {
    Get-WmiObject Win32_processor | select -ExpandProperty NumberOfLogicalProcessors
} 

Function cpumodel {
    Get-WmiObject Win32_processor | select -ExpandProperty Name
}

Function Memory {
    Get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem | select -ExpandProperty TotalPhysicalMemory
}

Function vendor {
    Get-WmiObject win32_bIOS  | select serialnumber
}

switch ($a) 
{ 
    pro {$(proc)} 
    cpu {$(cpumodel)}
    mem {$(Memory)} 
    default {$(proc);$(cpumodel);$(Memory)}
}
```

When I run the script, get the following result.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> powershell .\test.ps1
2
2
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           L7555  @ 1.87GHz
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           L7555  @ 1.87GHz
8589467648
```

In the above result, I want to 2 to be mentioned once, the following line to be mentioned once.

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           L7555  @ 1.87GHz
```

and the memory query result displayed in KB rather than bytes.

Now, I am from a Unix background and not very familiar with Powershell scripting, but I am learning.

Are there any cut, awk statement in Windows Powershell or What can I do to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're saying here, but I think you just need the `-ExpandProperty` option for `Select-Object`, like so:

```
param (
    [string]$a
)

Function proc {
    Get-WmiObject Win32_processor | select -ExpandProperty NumberOfLogicalProcessors
}

Function cpumodel {
    Get-WmiObject Win32_processor | select -ExpandProperty Name
}

Function Memory {
    Get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem | select -ExpandProperty TotalPhysicalMemory
}

Function vendor {
    Get-WmiObject win32_bIOS  | select -ExpandProperty serialnumber
}

switch ($a) {
    pro {$(proc)} 
    cpu {$(cpumodel)}
    mem {$(Memory)} 
}
```

Comment: Now, I am getting the following output. Is it possible to get only one of each for pro and cpu? 
PS C:\Users\Administrator> powershell .\test.ps1 pro
2
2
PS C:\Users\Administrator> powershell .\test.ps1 cpu
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           L7555  @ 1.87GHz
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           L7555  @ 1.87GHz
PS C:\Users\Administrator> powershell .\test.ps1 mem
8589467648

Comment: @RajS Try `Get-Unique`, like `Get-WmiObject Win32_processor | select -ExpandProperty NumberOfLogicalProcessors | Get-Unique`.

Comment: Get-Unique works for processor and cpu model info. I want the memory output to be displayed in kb, Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Thank you so far, Bacon bits. Please let me know if you can help with the final bit, else I will work something out and mark your answer.

Comment: `Function Memory {
$a = Get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem | select -ExpandProperty TotalPhysicalMemory


"{0:N0}" -f ($a / 1024)
}`

Comment: Above is two lines--line break after TotalPhysicalMemory

Comment: @RajS It depends what you want it to look like.  You could do something as simple as `(Get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem | select -ExpandProperty TotalPhysicalMemory) / 1KB` or you could format it to a string like `'{0:N2} KB' -f ((Get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem | select -ExpandProperty TotalPhysicalMemory) / 1KB)`

Comment: How is this not working for me? Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | select -Expand IPAddress. Select-Object : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "obj" is null. Change the value of argument "obj" to a non-null value.
At line:1 char:57
+ Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | select <<<<  -Expand IPAddress
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], PSArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNull,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand

Comment: PS C:\Users\Administrator> '{0:0}, Inc.' -f (Get-WmiObject win32_bIOS | select -Expand serialnumber) VMware-42 05 b1 01 ae 52 d1 ab-78 a0 28 c3 f9 10 ab 77, Inc. Is it possible to get the output as "VMware, Inc.". If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell works with objects, not text like Unix shells, so your `Get-WmiObject` calls produce objects of which the [`Select-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx) cmdlet (alias `select`) displays specific properties. If you want just the value of a specific property, you need to expand it. For instance:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_processor | select -Expand NumberOfLogicalProcessors
```

Also, you need to interpret the information at hand correctly. The `NumberOfLogicalProcessors` property does not give you the number of physical processors in the system. Instead it will give you the number of cores for each processor that doesn't support hyperthreading (same as `NumberOfCores`), or twice the number of cores for each hyperthreading enabled processor.

Quoting from the documentation of the [`Win32_Processor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class:

> **NumberOfLogicalProcessors**
>
> Data type: **uint32**
>   Access type: Read-only
>
> Number of logical processors for the current instance of the processor. For processors capable of hyperthreading, this value includes only the processors which have hyperthreading enabled. For more information, see Remarks.
>
> [...]
>
> **Remarks**
>
> On a multiprocessor computer, one instance of the **Win32_Processor** class exists for each processor.
>
> To determine the total number of processor instances associated with a computer system object, use the Win32_ComputerSystemProcessor association class.
>
> To determine if hyperthreading is enabled for the processor, compare **NumberOfLogicalProcessors** and **NumberOfCores**. If hyperthreading is enabled in the BIOS for the processor, then **NumberOfCores** is less than **NumberOfLogicalProcessors**. For example, a dual-processor system that contains two processors enabled for hyperthreading can run four threads or programs or simultaneously. In this case, **NumberOfCores** is 2 and **NumberOfLogicalProcessors** is 4.

If you want the number of physical processors, just count the number of objects `Get-WmiObject` returns:

```
@(Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor).Count
```

The `@()` ensures that the result is always an array (providing a `Count` property), even if returns just one (or zero) objects.

To get the unique Processor names, select the unique names:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_processor | select -Expand Name -Unique
```

And to transform a byte value into kilobytes, you can divide the value by `1024` or `1kb`. Use the [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) (`-f`) to format the resulting value appropriately:

```
$mem = Get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem | select -Expand TotalPhysicalMemory
'{0:f0} kB' -f ($mem / 1kb)
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to offer credit to more than one answer?

Comment: Not with the reputation you currently have.

Comment: Dang! One last question to you. PS C:\Users\Administrator> '{0:0}, Inc.' -f (Get-WmiObject win32_bIOS  | select -Expand serialnumber)
VMware-42 05 b1 01 ae 52 d1 ab-78 a0 28 c3 f9 10 ab 77, Inc. Is it possible to get the output as "VMware, Inc.". If yes, how?

Comment: You could remove everything from `-` up to `,`: `(...) -replace '-[^,]*'`. However, that won't necessarily handle other serial number strings correctly. If you're looking for a vendor name, you should probably rather look at the `Manufacturer` property of the [`Win32_ComputerSystem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class.